# Error when profiling keras models

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I want to profile my Keras model according to this [comment on github](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/9868). I use the tf.Keras API with Tensorflow version: 1.9.0-rc2 and Keras version: 2.1.6-tf.

```
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()

training_set = load_datasets(...) 
model.compile(loss=helpers.mean_categorical_crossentropy,optimizer='adam',options=run_options,run_metadata=run_metadata)
model.fit(training_set.make_one_shot_iterator(), steps_per_epoch=steps_per_epoch_train,epochs=num_epochs, verbose=2)

trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
```

Error

> ('Some keys in session_kwargs are not supported at this time: %s',
>   dict_keys(['options', 'run_metadata']))

In another [github post](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/6606) someone gives this example and somehow it runs without errors. I however get the same error as above.

```
import keras
from keras.layers.core import Dense
from keras.models import Sequential
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow.python.client import timeline
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randn(10000, 2)
y = (x[:, 0] * x[:, 1]) > 0 # xor
run_options = tf.RunOptions(trace_level=tf.RunOptions.FULL_TRACE)
run_metadata = tf.RunMetadata()
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(units=64, activation='relu', input_dim=2))
model.add(Dense(units=2, activation='softmax'))
model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              optimizer='sgd',
              options=run_options,
              run_metadata=run_metadata)
model.fit(x, keras.utils.to_categorical(y), epochs=1)
trace = timeline.Timeline(step_stats=run_metadata.step_stats)
with open('timeline.ctf.json', 'w') as f:
    f.write(trace.generate_chrome_trace_format())
```

I also found this [issue](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/issues/19911) on github which suggests that profiling with Keras models isn't implemented yet. I am confused.

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There's a pull request that fixes this: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/pull/19932

It's not merged yet to master, but I got it to work by merging it locally, or simply applying the changes manually to the installed tensorflow library

Comment: I implemented these changes and get `File "tensorflow_backend.py", line 2659, in _call run_metadata=self.run_metadata) TypeError: __call__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'run_metadata' `

Comment: This parameter is added by this PR. I would verify that the change was made to the correct copy of the file, or if there are left over precompiled versions of the file (*.pyc)

Comment: Thank you. I do not know for sure what fixed my issue, but I do not think I was using the exact same version of the repository as the one mentioned in the pull request. Updating to the `nightly` repository seemed to work.